# SDL2/C : How am i suppose to blit and refresh textures?

Tags: c, textures, sdl-2, blit

I'm trying to develop a platformer-like, but i'm stuck in the way i'm displaying all my textures.

Pseudo-code:

```
Texture background = bg.png
Texture player = player.png

display(background)

while (run)

    if (player.moved)
        player.refresh = true

    if (player.refresh)
        display(player)
```

Globally i'm doing like this to display my textures.

But when i'm moving my player (left, right etc.) the old texture of this one is always displayed.

everywhere i'm searching how to do it, i see people doing this :

```
Texture background = bg.png
Texture player = player.png

while (run)

    display(background)
    display(player)
```

They always blit all their textures, but it's absolutely not optimised. they blit texture that havn't moved.

So can someone tell me the good way to blit and refresh textures ?

Comment: Almost all modern games are written to redraw the entire screen every frame.

Comment: user253751 But it take useless performance ?

Comment: Does it? Or does it save performance because it doesn't need to figure out what to blit? Especially if you are using the GPU, the GPU really likes to start from scratch every frame and it's good at blitting big textures.

Comment: Depends on the game. If your display is so static and interactions are extremely rare - maybe it makes sense to reduce redraw to... save battery on mobile device? Oftentimes image is dynamic (e.g. animated background, character idle animation, etc.) even if no player input happens. If you really want to go that way - you have to redraw changed regions (i.e. both new player position and 'erase' with background its old position), but you also have to consider doublebuffering - meaning the frame you're processing now could be one-before-previous, not previous. In short - not worth the effort.

Comment: Also sometimes framebuffer (or its part) could be invalidated after being minimised, resized or overshadowed by other windows. In that case you need to redraw that regions.